# SQL Server 2008 Stored proc - Optimizer thinks my parameter is nullable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, null

Optimizer seems to be getting confused about the null-ability of a varchar parameter and I'm not sure I understand why. I'm using SQL Server 2008 btw. All columns being queried are indexed. The TDate column is a clustered, partitioned index. The FooValue column is indexed, non-nullable column.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyExample_sp @SDate DATETIME, @EDate DATETIME, @FooValue VARCHAR(50)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

--To avoid parameter spoofing / sniffing
DECLARE @sDate1 DATETIME, @eDate1 DATETIME
SET @sDate1 = @sDate
SET @eDate1 = @eDate

SELECT
    fd.Col1,
    fd.Col2,
    fd.TDate,
    fl.FooValue,
    fd.AccountNum
FROM dbo.FooData fd
INNER JOIN dbo.FooLookup fl
    ON fl.FL_ID = fd.FL_ID
WHERE fd.TDate >= @sDate1
    AND fd.TDate < @eDate1
    AND fl.FooValue = @FooValue
```

Running this as a query works as expected. All indexes are seeks, no spoofing etc. Running this by executing the sproc takes 20 times longer - same query - same parameters. However, if I make the following change (very last line) everything works again.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyExample_sp @SDate DATETIME, @EDate DATETIME, @FooValue VARCHAR(50)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

--To avoid parameter spoofing / sniffing
DECLARE @sDate1, @eDate1
SET @sDate1 = @sDate
SET @eDate1 = @eDate

SELECT
    fd.Col1,
    fd.Col2,
    fd.TDate,
    fl.FooValue,
    fd.AccountNum
FROM dbo.FooData fd
INNER JOIN dbo.FooLookup fl
    ON fl.FL_ID = fd.FL_ID
WHERE fd.TDate >= @sDate1
    AND fd.TDate < @eDate1
    AND fl.FooValue = ISNULL(@FooValue, 'testthis')
```

It's like the optimizer is getting confused about whether the parameter is nullable or not?  Also, adding a default value to the parameter doesn't make any difference. It still takes forever for the sproc to run unless I use = isnull(@parameter, 'some constant')

I'm happy I figured this out. But, I'd like to understand why this is happening and if there was a more elegant way to resolve the issue.

Comment: The variable *is* nullable.  Is your question why a nullable variable affects the query plan?  or is it why the variable is considered nullable?

Comment: I guess it would be the latter. Now that I've run into this, I can see why the variable is considered nullable (I can pass in a null of course).

But, why the query plan gets all screwed up is confusing to me. PS: Is there a better way to tell SQL that a variable cannot be null? Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: One way is to write the query as dynamic SQL, with the variables hard-coded as values in the string.  When you run the string, it gets compiled at that time, so it should choose the optimal query plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re: Nullable variables**

There is no concept of nullable for variables in T-SQL, the way that you can define a variable as nullable in c# using the ?.
If you have a parameter in a stored procedure, the end user can pass whatever he or she wants into the stored procedure, be it a real value or a null.

**Re: the query plan**

The query plan that will get cached is the query plan that gets generated upon the first time you call this stored procedure.. so if you passed in a null for @FooValue the very first time you ran it, then it will be optimized for @FooValue = null.

There is an [OPTIMIZE FOR](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1354/optimize-parameter-driven-queries-with-sql-server-optimize-for-hint/) hint that you can use to optimize the query for some other value:

Or you can use [WITH RECOMPILE](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2008/03/with-recompile-re-compile-execution.html), which will force the query plan to get regenerated on every run of the stored procedure.

Obviously there are trade-offs when using these types of hints, so make sure you understand them before using them.